# Save AKSequencer output to local file

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm having issues while saving a midi using a sequencer to a local file.
The audio is being created and saved, but the audio output is completely different as it should be.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var sequencer : AKSequencer?
let piano = AKMIDISampler()
var offlineRender = AKOfflineRenderNode()

do {
   try piano.loadWav("mixloop")

   piano >>> offlineRender

   AudioKit.output = offlineRender
   sequencer = AKSequencer(filename: "melody")
   sequencer?.setGlobalMIDIOutput(piano.midiIn)

   AudioKit.start()

   let docs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
   let destAudioFile = docs.appendingPathComponent("rendered11.caf")

   offlineRender.internalRenderEnabled = false
   self.sequencer?.play()
   let seconds = sequencer?.length.seconds
   try self.offlineRender.renderToURL(destAudioFile, seconds: seconds ?? 4)
   self.sequencer!.stop()

   self.offlineRender.internalRenderEnabled = true
   print("Done! Rendered to " + destAudioFile.path)

   // test the local song using just AVAudioPlayer
   playLocalSong(url: destAudioFile)

} catch {
   print(error)
   return
}
```

I'm attaching the mixloop.wav, melody.mid and the output rendered11.caf. [files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0-hfmdUuApIM2M3TXBsSEt6R1E/view?usp=sharing)

And if I change this line:

```
AudioKit.output = offlineRender
```

to

```
AudioKit.output = piano
```

The sound is just as it should be, with 16 seconds of sound instead of just the first few seconds.

Is something wrong in the code above?

Thanks in advance